# Make three item row into four item row after sidebar is collapsed

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

If you take a look at the demo, you will see a bunch of cards in one row. But there should be only three cards in one row, and if you click the "collapse sidebar" it should change it up to four cards per row.

The cards should also have a fixed with and not be too wide even if you
re using bigger screens. 
I am aware, that the demo has all of the cards in one row at the moment.

Thanks alot! :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TEST</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="button--sidebarCollapse">
      <a class="button--collapse" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseExample"> >COLLAPSE SIDEBAR</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row h-100">
      <!-- SIDEBAR FILTER CONTENT -->
      <div class="col-2 collapse show form--sidebarContents" id="collapseExample">
        <div class="p-2">
          <form class="form-row my-2 my-lg-0 form--search">
            <p>lorem ipsum placeholder</p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col h-100 cards--mainContent">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card-deck">
            <div class="card" data-toggle="collapsed" aria-expanded="false" id="sidebar" data-target="sidebar">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">little bit longer.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text"> is a little bit longer.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is a</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Th a little bit longer.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please use the local HTML/JS playground. Also, please remove redundant and irrelevant parts of code - provide an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Stack overflow isn't a code writing service, have you tried to implement any of these features yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I tried playing around with columns, rows and also cards, but nothing seemed to work like I wanted it to. Perhaps I used them wrong. That's the reason why I came here to look for advice or help. 
At the moment I can't quite get the cards to appear in columns that consist of three items per row.